# How can I add bigger image in my blog post?

Tags: images, blog

Right now I simply write my content and click to add media from the "Site Origin Editor" but the images are of thumbnail size on the blog post , how can i add images to be displayed bigger in size, at least that can be viewed without clicking on it or zooming.

right now it's like this : http://www.goforazhar.com/how-to-download-youtube-videos/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have fetched the thumbnail size image.

You can fetch/show the full image url that you have uploaded using

```
$imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), "full" );
$imgsrc = $imgsrc[0];
echo $imgsrc;
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Aishan , the image i have fetched is not a thumbnail size, it is a bigger size landscape image , and the code you have writter here , where should i paste this ?

Comment: you can find the code where the image previously were called on your video page and replace with the above code. And please make sure that $imgsrc is placed like 
<img src="<?php echo $imgsrc;?>">
That will then pull out your actual uploaded image.